# C# accepting Image as HttpPostedFile in Restful API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, post, fiddler

I'm building a rest api in C# - and I'm setting up some POST's - here's the interface:

```
    [SecurityTokenValidator("Registered Users")]
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "camps/{campid}/markings/{token}", Method = "POST")]
    MarkingDto InsertMarking(string campid, string token, MarkingDto markingDto);
```

And here's my MarkingDto

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "FreeBeer")]
public class MarkingDto
{
    [DataMember] public int Id;
    [DataMember] public decimal Latitude;
    [DataMember] public decimal Longitude;
    [DataMember] public string MarkingType;
    [DataMember] public DateTime DateTime;
}
```

In building up a test POST in Fiddler - I'm noticing if my RequestBody isn't in Alphabetical order - some items come up null or zero.  For instance - if the request body is like so - where Longitude comes BEFORE Latitude - Latitude will be zero (0).

```
<MarkingDto xmlns="BigGameLogic">
<Longitude>456</Longitude>
<Latitude>123</Latitude>
<MarkingType>Scrape</MarkingType>
</MarkingDto>
```

But if kept in alphabetical order - everything is there.  Is this just a Fiddler thing?  Or is this something I need to fix because of the easy solution I'm missing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a requirement in WCF that unless you specify an order on the DataMember that member properties are sent in alphabetical order.

See the answer to this question resently

[Not all parameters in WCF data contract make it through the web service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474838/not-all-parameters-in-wcf-data-contract-make-it-through-the-web-service-call/10475117#10475117)

More info can be found here

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - like on the other SO question by @Robert Harvey - type of stuff that makes programmers want to strangle someone